# Creating a custom module in Magento 1.9

Tags: adminhtml

How we can a create a custom module in magentho 1.9?

For this I created a new module inside `app/code/loacl/display`. Here **display** is the directory I have created. Inside **display** I have created a new folder **customgrid**. Inside Customgrid I have created Block, Helper, Model and Controller.

I need to know one thing where I will create a view page for my controller and How I will get the data from the view page to controller and How can I insert my data to database

I have attached the screen shot I need to create a view page like this in admin side.

[image]

This is the view page I need in the admin side. I need to change the value inside each coloum that I will create.

Comment: This is a nice place to learn extension development in magento 1.x - https://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world/

Comment: i need to know where  i should create the view page for my controller and i need to know how the relation between controller and view is extablished

Comment: i have already attached screen shot in my question i need to develope something like that in adminhtml

Comment: @melvinmk there is the layout(xml) involved to link the controller with the view. which you basically find under design/frontend/layout/your-module-layout.xml . There are handler for each controller inside which you have to define the block and link the template to it. You need to have detail info on module to know all this.

Comment: it is not in magentho 2 it is in magentho 1.1

Comment: How can I load a custom view .phtml file in adminside

Comment: If you check the link i added in my answer you can create a whole module with custom admin template ready made, you just need to add the content there, if you are asking that for. Above comment is for magento 1.x but for frontend, same logic will be applied for adminhtml too, but those template file will reside on adminhtml folder instead of frontend folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are series of steps you need to perform to create a module in magento.

1. Name the Package name and Module name properly (Follow the naming convention the name should be in capital).
2. The folder name is case sensitive, your controller file will reside inside "controllers", use exact naming convention.

You will find lots of tutorial which will guide you step by step in magento module creation please follow one. you can see [this](https://www.multidots.com/step-by-step-guide-for-magento-module-development) .

If you need to quick create module with base files and blocks defined you can use [module creator for magento 1.x](https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) . Using this you can quickly create your module, but first its better you learn how you can create the module from scratch, this will help you understand the full flow of the module which is very necessary for understanding the flow.

Hope this helps. If yes please don't forget to accept and vote up the answer. This will help others to find this answer.

Happy coding!!